# Have anyone had experience in installing nodejs on OpenSUSE 11SP2?

Tags: node.js, opensuse, suse

The system environments are:

```
openSUSE 11.2
gcc: 4.3.4
gmake: 3.8.1
Python: 2.6, 2.7
Internet: no public internet access, only inbound via ssh/sftp.
```

Due to no internet access, I have to install all my apps from **local**, either from rpm or **source file**.

As the title says how can I install **nodejs from source file**? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I think for the installation you need internet access, because nodejs will download the npm packages.

Comment: the problem i am facing now is that the system has no libv8.so.3.